# Why don't the textfields and buttons in my div react to clicks?

Tags: javascript, html, textfield, popupwindow

For school homework, I'm creating a single page with another student. Our teacher gave us an HTML-File to clone some of the components for our own project, so that we don't have to write it from scratch. We want to create our own .js file with some listeners for the components we take from her file.

The below code produces a label called "keywords" with a question mark icon to its right and a text field further right. A click on the question mark icon opens a popup window with some options and the text field allows comma-separated strings as "keywords". Our problem is that on our HTML-Page, all these elements show up with no problem, but the popup window won't show up when we click on the question mark icon and the text field is also not activated when we click on it.

We looked at our teacher's HTML file and played on it a bit. We found out, that when we remove her js file as a script the same thing happens on her HTML file too. So we looked into her js file and checked the 55.000 lines long js file for some reference to these elements and found nothing. So we don't know, why ours doesn't work. The console shows no errors in the output when we open our HTML file. How can we make these elements respond to clicks? where should we look for errors, mistakes?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-3" for="offer_tag_list">
    <div class="inline-help form-label" data-help="&lt;b&gt;You would like to use keywords:&lt;/b&gt; In that case use one or more words for each keyword and use a comma to seperate.
br&gt;
&lt;b&gt;You want to remove a keyword?&lt;/b&gt; Then click on the &lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-remove&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; symbol at the end of that keyword.
  &lt;div class=&quot;panel panel-default&quot; id=&quot;feedback-form&quot;&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;panel-heading&quot;&gt;
      &lt;h4 class=&quot;panel-title&quot;&gt;
        &lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-question-circle&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; Was that information useful? &lt;/h4&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;panel-body&quot;&gt;
      &lt;form class=&quot;feedback&quot; role=&quot;form&quot; id=&quot;new_feedback&quot; action=&quot;/feedbacks&quot; accept-charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot; data-remote=&quot;true&quot; method=&quot;post&quot;&gt;&lt;input name=&quot;utf8&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;&amp;#x2713;&quot; /&gt;
        &lt;div class=&quot;form-group&quot;&gt;&lt;textarea placeholder=&quot;You can write comments here.&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; name=&quot;feedback[comment]&quot; id=&quot;feedback_comment&quot;&gt;
&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;input type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;/offers/new&quot; name=&quot;feedback[context]&quot; id=&quot;feedback_context&quot; /&gt;
        &lt;input type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;offers.tag_list&quot; name=&quot;feedback[help_key]&quot; id=&quot;feedback_help_key&quot; /&gt;
        &lt;div class=&quot;actions&quot;&gt;          &lt;input type=&quot;submit&quot; name=&quot;feedback[helpful]&quot; value=&quot;Ja&quot; class=&quot;btn btn-default&quot; data-disable-with=&quot;Ja&quot; /&gt;          &lt;input type=&quot;submit&quot; name=&quot;feedback[helpful]&quot; value=&quot;Nein&quot; class=&quot;btn btn-default&quot; data-disable-with=&quot;Nein&quot; /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/form&gt;      &lt;div class=&quot;hidden response&quot;&gt;
        Thank you for your Feedback!
      &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
" data-heading="How to use keywords?" data-help-key="offers.tag_list">
      <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o"></i>
    </div>Keywords
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
    <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
      <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
        <input type="text" class="tt-hint" readonly="" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1" dir="ltr" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; opacity: 1; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
        <input type="text" placeholder="" class="tt-input" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" aria-activedescendant="" aria-owns="undefined_listbox" role="combobox" aria-readonly="true" aria-autocomplete="list" style="">
        <span role="status" aria-live="polite" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; border: 0px; height: 1px; width: 1px; margin-bottom: -1px; margin-right: -1px; overflow: hidden; clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px); white-space: nowrap;"></span>
        <pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 28px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;"></pre>
        <div role="listbox" class="tt-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;">
          <div role="presentation" class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-tags"></div>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
    <input value="" data-use-tagsinput="true" class="form-control" type="text" name="offer[tag_list]" id="offer_tag_list" style="display: none;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit and insert your code again without HTML escaping it. I can see already you haven't added any events to the elements though.

Comment: If you remove the JavaScript file, then of course the JavaScript will not work.

Comment: True, we haven't added listeners yet. Because we are still working on getting our html elements right. What do you mean by "without HTML escaping it"?@Turnip, yes I  know that. I just wasnt aware that the above functionalities were related to it. still learning.